# 'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules \npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com mand,

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

```
C:\Users\MNE GO DIGITAL>npm
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand,
```

operable program or batch file.

i have installed nodejs on c drive
when i hit npm --v also it state this same error

```
C:\Users\MNE GO DIGITAL>npm
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand,
```

operable program or batch file.

please find attachment for more clarification [image]

[image]Error in executing npm on windows 7

Answer (score 3):

I just spend way to long with this issue. I'm not sure how it got set, perhaps during an install, but I changed a System Variable:

Name: ComSpec Value: %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;prefix=C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe

To this:

Name: ComSpec Value: %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe

And restarted my system and the issue was gone.

Comment: this fixed it for me

Comment: And what does that step actually do? What if my ComSpec value doesn't look like the one you had in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

@selva,
For start some server with npm, you can use

```
npm start
```

A package can be downloaded with the command

`npm install <package_name>`

For install globally use `-g` after package name.

If there is no `package.json` file in the **local directory**, the latest version of the package is installed.

If there is `package.json` file, the latest version satisfying the semver rule declared in `package.json` for that package (if there is any) is *installed*.

`npm` only, does not anything. The command wait for something to do, install, help, etc.

If the problem with command npm --v continuous, try uninstall and install again.

**Check this solution:**

I saw your problem is with npm-cli,
You need to Add C:\Program Files\nodejs to your PATH environment variable. To do this follow these steps:

Go to control panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings then environment variables.

- Use the global Search Charm to search "Environment Variables"
- Click "Edit system environment variables"
- Click "Environment Variables" in the dialog.
- In the "System Variables" box, search for Path and edit it to include `C:\Program Files\nodejs`. Make sure it is separated from any other paths by a `;`.
  You will have to restart any currently-opened command prompts before it will take effect.

See more at official documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally).

Comment: I have tried uninstall and re-install also and tried npm start also but the same error occurs every time

Comment: I have checked that also please look the last image which i have posted for your reference now ..it actually return version with error above

Comment: Your node is installed in C:, try use C: inside prompt, and after use npm --v

Comment: NPM request for you to try inside C: because the node is install in C:

Comment: If the problem continue, try use the command `npm cache clean`, and after uninstall and install the node + npm again

Comment: can u able to take my system in remote??? i have checked environment variable it is there C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;C:\Users\MNE GO DIGITAL\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: In this case, you use the prompt now? Try type C: and press enter, after try use npm... npm --v

Comment: Try install the TeamViewer and pass your id e password

Comment: It has to be fast. I have to go to School

Comment: hey am sorry i couldn't make that on time ping me here selva1990kumar@gamil.com about your convenient time i ll give access