# Why does all npm commands show the following error?

Tags: node.js, batch-file, npm, cmd

I installed node.js. When I tested it by running the command `node -v` it works fine. But when I try to run `npm -v` it gives me the following error:

```
'CALL "C:\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Then after showing that error, it shows the version. It basically shows this error on all *npm commands*, including `npm install` commands. I have tried installing the same version on other machines and it works fine. However, the other machines are running Windows 10. Mine is running **Windows 8.1**.

**EDIT**: I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling node, it didn't fix the issue.

Content of `npm.cmd` of **Node.js** v12.15.0:

```
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL

SET "NODE_EXE=%~dp0\node.exe"
IF NOT EXIST "%NODE_EXE%" (
  SET "NODE_EXE=node"
)

SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%~dp0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('CALL "%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" prefix -g') DO (
  SET "NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS=%%F\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
)
IF EXIST "%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%" (
  SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%"
)

"%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" %*
```

Comment: @Compo I didn't call an ```.exe``` file explicitly. I just typed ```npm -v``` and it printed that out. I even checked the *npm.cmd* file to make sense of the code inside, I don't seem to understand it.

Comment: Do either of these questions help? [1.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51003183), [2.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43312904).

Comment: the error message states that it can't find a command or file `CALL "C:\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g` (yes, literally the whole string is considered a single command/filename. Check, where this line gets executed and show us the relevant code (I suspect there is some wrong quoting). `Npm` itself is innocent, `node.exe` doesn't even get executed.

Comment: @Compo no they didn't help

Comment: @Stephan How do I check that? I'm guessing it's the file ```npm.cmd```, is that correct?

Comment: what happens when you run `where node` from `cmd`?