# 'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" is not recognised as an internal order or external, an executable program or a command file

Tags: node.js, npm

I have just installed node and npm, and when i do npm - v, i get the following message :
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognised as an internal order
or external, an executable program or a command file.

6.14.6

I have tried to change my PATH, and reinstalling, but there is still the same message.

Comment: There is an unnecessary space in "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules \npm\bin\npm-cli.js". Maybe it is your issue?

Comment: how do i change that space ?

Comment: Did you try to run this command manually?

Comment: no i did not, how can i do that ?

Comment: open cmd, and run `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules \npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g`

Comment: hi, i did that and the result is : 'C:\Program' is not recognised as an internal or external command.

Comment: You should execute exactly as I indicated with double quotes

Comment: with the double quotes the result is : internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules \npm\bin\npm-cl
.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.j
:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Comment: Can you check an existence of `npm-cli.js` in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin` folder?

Comment: the file exists in this folder

Comment: Run `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g`

Comment: hi, the result of this querry is : C:\Users\Amal.AMAL-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: Ok, it's a start then. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312904/call-c-program-files-nodejs-node-modules-npm-bin-npm-cli-js-prefix-g-is/43638412#43638412

Comment: thanks for your help, it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

So the trick was that you have to delete the system variable "ComSpec" with the value of "%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe" After doing this you add a new system variable with the name "ComSpec" and a value set to "%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe" As stupid as this sounds it will resolve this idiotic issue windows 10 is causing itself. It's almost as if you're telling windows 10 "Hey I know you're confused but here is the right path..."